# Bootstrap table-hover border-top color change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The table-hover class in bootstrap applies the default border-top with color of grey to all the rows. [see getBootstrap definition](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

How do I change the border-top color for all the rows?
I know I can change the hover background color using the following:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
background-color: white;
}
```

Adding

```
border-color:1px solid black;
```

won't work.

Adding

```
.table {
  border-color: 1px solid black;
}
```

also won't work.

Here is my table structure

```
.tab {
    font-size:1em;
    color:black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin-top:60px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
  }


<div class="container">
    <div class="tab">
        <table class="table table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>All Users</b></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                something..
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change border color like this:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td, 
.table > tbody > tr > th {
    border-top-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It works. I found out this also works  
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: #ffff99;
}
```

check out this 
 http://jsfiddle.net/Lhh3f8eo/

Answer (score 1):

```
.table-hover tr:hover td, .table-hover tr:hover th {
   border-top-color: #fff;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/713e9a85/)